# How to get OperationContext from an attribute implementing IServiceBehavior/IOperationBehavior

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-extensions

I have a Attribute implementing IServiceBehavior to secure my WCF services, like below:

```
public class AuthorizedServiceAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    #region IServiceBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        var token = string.Empty; // to do: get the token from message headers

        foreach (var operation in serviceHostBase.Description.Endpoints
            .SelectMany(endpoint => endpoint.Contract.Operations))
        {
            operation.Behaviors.Add(new AuthorizedMethodAttribute { Token = token });
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    { }

    #endregion
}
```

The problem is in order to get the message headers, I have to get the current OperationContext but I don't know how to to do it inside the ApplyDispatchBehavior. If I do it in the methods under secure, it works.

Comment: You can have access to the property from IDispatchMessageInspector or IParameterInspector implementation. What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is: from the client I will attach a token into the message header and then get that token from server via attributes to validate the client

Comment: @Legart: Thank you so much! I did succeed with the IParameterInspector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case I would suggest to use Message contract: [Message Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Or you can also use IDispatchMessageInspector: [Message Inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961589/wcf-afterreceiverequest-get-headers), or IParameterInspector  as I mentioned in comments.